# How to create key value data type in django 1.7 models

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-custom-field

I want to store key-value pair in one column.

Above >Django-1.7 provides hstore to do that.

But I want to same functionality in Django-1.7.

How can I create custom datatype to store key-value pair in one column.

I am using postgres-9.5 database.

I want to store below json in key value pair in one column.

Example:

```
{
    "prepared_date":"2016-08-08T02:04:34Z",
    "date_0":"2016-08-08T02:04:34Z",
    "status_0":true,
    "date_1":"2016-08-08T02:04:34Z",
    "status_1":true,
    "date_2":"2016-08-08T02:04:34Z",
    "status_2":true,
}
```

Comment: why don't you just write the json als string into your database?

Comment: I did that, But the problem is to make query on it. Or change the value of specific key.

Comment: What kind of queries do you want to execute on this sort of data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a nice package exactly for this purpose:

http://djangonauts.github.io/django-hstore/

So just install using pip:

```
pip install django-hstore
```

Comment: This is what I want, Thanks for quick response